# jQuery detect android back button press and act

Tags: android, jquery, html, video, back

I using a html video on my webpage and I've noticed on android phones when the video goes to full screen and I press the back button, it just leaves and empty video player frame with the pause button showing. Is there a way to hide the empty player or the div that contains the video when the user presses the back button on their phone?

I'm currently using the the events js for the video tag and have added the mobile jquery pack in the hopes for an if back button press do this.

Any help on this would be great as it's all working fine on the web version and on an ipad/iphone.